# Operaciones aritméticas simples

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Tengo un problema a la hora de hacer la multiplicación, la suma y la resta en el siguiente algoritmo, no sabría que error puede llegar a ser.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ingrese dos numeros"  
read num1 num2  
mul = $num1 * $num2  
sum = $num1 + $num2
resta = $num1 - $num2

echo "La multiplicacion es $mul"  
echo "La suma es $sum"  
echo "La resta es $resta"  

if [ $num1 -gt $num2 ]; then  
     echo "El mayor es $num1"  
else  
    echo "El mayor es $num2"    
fi
```

Comment: https://bioinf.comav.upv.es/courses/unix/scripts_bash.html#operaciones-aritmticas    fijate acá!

Comment: Justo u nrato despues de que lo publicara me habia fijado en esa pagina jajaja y lo solucione, muchas gracias por responder!

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ingrese dos numeros"  
read num1 num2  
mul = $(($num1 * $num2))
sum = $(($num1 + $num2))
resta = $(($num1 - $num2))

echo "La multiplicacion es $mul"  
echo "La suma es $sum"  
echo "La resta es $resta"  

if [ $num1 -gt $num2 ]; then  
     echo "El mayor es $num1"  
else  
    echo "El mayor es $num2"    
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera en la que puedes realizar es con [].

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ingrese dos numeros"
read num1 num2
mul=$[ $num1 * $num2 ]
sum=$[$num1 + $num2 ]
resta=$[ $num1 - $num2 ]

echo "La multiplicacion es $mul"
echo "La suma es $sum"
echo "La resta es $resta"

if [ $num1 -gt $num2 ]; then
     echo "El mayor es $num1"
else
    echo "El mayor es $num2"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay que recordar que bash no es php ;)

El manual de bash establece que para hacer cierto tipo de operaciones utiliza algo llamado *arithmetic expansion*, en la sección de `EXPANSIONS` en la que se usan los caracteres `$((expresión))` para evaluar la expresión y luego sustituirla.

Además, en la sección de `PARAMETERS` viene información sobre como asignar una variable en la cual se muestra que la sintaxis debe ser la siguiente.

> PARAMETERS
>
> (...)
>
> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> ```
> name=[value]
> ```
>
> If  value  is  not given, the variable is assigned the null string.  All values undergo tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion,  and  quote  removal
>
> (...)

Es decir, en lugar de:

```
mul = $num1 * $num2
```

Tendría que ser de la forma:

```
(...)
mul=$((num1 * num2)) #evaluando la expresión ingresándola dentro de una *aritmethic expansion*
#  ^ Respetando el que no haya espacios.
(...)
```

A diferencia de lo propuesto por @l10nn y @HabemusCode, se puede prescindir de los caracteres "$" antes de cada variable puesto que se fuerza a que cada token ingresado se someta a ciertas expansiones. Esto es una especie de atajo ofrecida.

Y, a diferencia de lo propuesto por @l10nn, el manual establece que la sintaxis `[ expresión ]` es obsoleta y será removida en versiones posteriores de bash.

> Arithmetic Expansion
>
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic  expression  and  the  substitution  of  the
>     result.  The format for arithmetic expansion is:
>
> $((expression))
>
> The old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.
>
> The  expression is treated as if it were within double quotes, but a double quote inside the parentheses is not treated specially.  All tokens in the expression undergo parameter and variable  expansion,  command  substitution,  and quote removal.
>
> (...)